# 500 error at System > Configuration > Shipping Methods

Tags: magento-1.9

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in /Users/camdixon/Sites/snowcommerce/dfs/dfs.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

When I click on System, configuration, and then "Shipping Methods" I get this error on my local machine.  I do not get this error for any other links. How would you go about fixing?

Comment: in root of the site, you can see `index.php` file, take backup of that file and than uncommnet thisl ine : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` and than check what error is coming, also check var/log folder errors....

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that the system config option source model is returning false or true, when the system is expecting an array. Because a boolean can't be converted to an array, the system crashes and execution stops.

To work on fixing this, I'd look into the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form`, and look to see what line this is happening on. It's likely going to be obfuscated, so I'd take an audit of third-party and custom modules that are installed that interact with the system configuration area and look for the statement `return true;` or `return false;` or anything else that could be returning a boolean value instead of an array.